# TF r2.3 Bad Address build issue on windows

Tags: windows, tensorflow, build, nvidia

I have a problem with building TF r2.3 when I would like to build a version with CUDA support. When I configure the build for CPU without CUDA everything build fine. With the CUDA support turned on I got Bad address (Exit 126) error for bash commands like this. I use windows 10 with MSVC 2019 v16.6.5. I also use python 3.6.8 and Bazel 3.3.1. I have encountered with this problem with both CUDA v10.2, cudnn-10.2-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32 and CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN 7.4. I have tried to build with the following command after I have configured the project.

```
bazel build --config=opt --define=no_tensorflow_py_deps=true //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so
```

I put the content of the command.log file to this [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/CK0VxEcF).

I have opened a [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41850) for this error on the tensorflow repo but so far they haven't provided any solution for this issue. I hope here someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is your resolved now? Else, can you try to completely uninstall all the packages try a fresh install as a workaround.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, try to build TF 2.4 with Cuda 11 and cuDNN 8. I was able to build with this configuration on Windows finally.